# C++ class method not working when called inside class

Tags: c++, oop

I am new to StackOverflow and C++. I started to make a bank program but ran into a problem where the `AddMoney()` function does not work in `Tranfer()` function of class `BankAccount`. I tried running it in `main()` and there it works. I also tried to just directly add to the `balance` variable and this also works. No errors are shown. Btw, `Transfer()` function deducts money with `DeductMoney()`(This func works btw) and then adds it to another account with `AddMoney()`. Feedbacks appreciated on how to generally improve my code. Thanks in advance.

The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class BankAccount
{
    string name;
    int accno;
    void DeductMoney(float);
    void Transactions(BankAccount,float);
    public:
        // void AddMoney(float);
        float balance;
        BankAccount(string a,float b = 0)
        {
            name = a;
            balance = b;
            string var;

            accno = rand();
            /* for (int i;i<7;i++)
            {
                var += "rand() % 10";
            };
            accno = (int)var; */

        }
        void Transfer(BankAccount,float);
        void Interest(float);
        void Display(void)
        {
            cout << "Name of account: " << name << endl;
            cout << "Balance: " << balance << endl;

        };

};
/* void BankAccount :: AddMoney(float e)
{
    //cout << "Money added " << e << endl;
    //cout << "Adding Money to accno: " << accno << endl;
    balance += e;
} */
void BankAccount :: DeductMoney(float b)
{
    balance -= b;
    cout << "Deducting money from accno: " << accno << endl;
}
void BankAccount :: Transfer(BankAccount a,float b)
{
    cout << "Transfering..." << endl;
    this->DeductMoney(b);
    a.balance += b;
    this->Transactions(a,b);
    a.balance += b;

}
void BankAccount :: Interest(float intrst = 0.18)
{
    balance += balance * intrst;
    cout << "Interst added: " << balance*intrst << endl;
}
void BankAccount :: Transactions(BankAccount a,float b)
{
    cout << name << " transferred " << b << " to " << a.name << endl;
}
main()
{
    BankAccount C1("Abcd",100.0);
    BankAccount B2("Degf",200.0);
    //C1.AddMoney(50.0);
    B2.Transfer(C1,50.0);
    C1.Display();
    B2.Display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *the `AddMoney()` function does not work in `Tranfer()` function* What made you conclude that?

Comment: @R Sahu As pointed by MikeCAT I was passing reference and it wasn't changing the original value.

Comment: * You were passing by value, the solution is to pass by reference.

Answer (score 2):

In this function:

```cpp
void BankAccount :: Transfer(BankAccount a,float b)
```

The `a` parameter is a *copy of* what is passed to it, so modifications to that *copy* will not affect the original that is passed in.

If the modifications should apply to the original, you should add `&` after `BankAccount` (for both declaration and definition) to make it a reference.

```cpp
void BankAccount :: Transfer(BankAccount& a,float b)
```